# How to read chrome dev console profile chart

Tags: google-chrome, profiling

All:

Im pretty new to Chrome JS console. Right now I just start to use profiling tool to record:

Say I have a very simple function call stack:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(){
        var n = Math.random()*100;
        if(n>50){
            return "Hello!"
        }else {
            return "Nihao!"
        }
    }
    function hellosb(name){
        console.log( hello()+" "+name );
    }
    function show(){
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
                hellosb(i*j+"");
            }
        }
    }
    show();
</script>
```

And I got result like this(part related to call stack):

[image]

**I am not sure how to read it, for example:**

1. There should be multiple call to hellosb() and hello(), it only show one in the chart,  where can I find them all?
2. How can I track back to its caller if there is some async event call?

Answer (score 0):

You've set your scroll bars to show the activity between 1628ms and 1656ms, an interval of 28ms.
What you're looking at is an inverted flame graph of what happened in that time.
As you can see, it was mostly spent in `show()` calling `hellosb()` in a call to `console.log`. What looks like a single call could just as well be numerous calls.

It appears as though Chrome Dev Tools Profiler is a stack-sampling profiler, so it is unlikely to see very short-lived situations, like the time between `hellosb` returning and the next time it is called.
Also, notice it does not report how many times `hellosb` or other routines are called, which makes sense because samplers do not count calls.

This is OK, because the usual purpose of profiling is to find code that is responsible for a large fraction of time (not a small fraction), so you can look there to see if anything it is doing can be removed.
This does not require knowing how many times the code was executed.
If it is executed an excessive number of times, that can be seen in its callers.

Comment: Thanks, one thing I want to clear: so you mean the reason is those hello() calls are not caught by Chrome, right? If so, will that mean the chart showing call stack is potentially wrong too?(for example, that light purple hello() should not at same level as other log)

Comment: @Kuan: I don't think it's wrong. `hellosb` is called 100 times, but the time between calls is so incredibly short that no samples strike in those intervals, so it looks like one long call. That is not surprising. On the other hand `hellosb` spends part of its time calling `log` and part of its time calling `hello`, which makes sense from the way it is written. There's nothing wrong here. Sampling profilers do not pay any attention to the events of functions being entered or exited, and as I tried to say, that's OK because those events don't matter.